# systemd.unit `RequiresMountsFor=` vs `ConditionPathIsDirectory=`

Tags: systemd, systemd-timer

I am about to write service that `rsync --delete` directory /mnt/foo to remote server. However because of `--delete` option, I'd like to not run it unless /mnt/foo is mounted, as this might result in deletion of all files on remote.

What to achieve it with `ConditionX` (e.g. `ConditionPathIsDirectory`) and `RequiresMountsFor=` directives, and what is the difference (pros and cons of each) ?

Draft:
Here is my current sketch:

```
RequiresMountsFor=/mnt/foo
```

vs

```
# assuming there is `bar_only_on_foo` subdirectory on monted directory, which does not exis on unmounted one.
ConditionPathIsDirectory=/mnt/foo/bar_only_on_foo
```

To add to `.service` file:

```
# /etc/systemd/system/rsync_to_remotey.service
# or : /home/$USER/.config/systemd/user/rsync_to_remotey.service
[Unit]
Description=rsync USER X data to REMOTE Y

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/USERX/rsync_userx_to_remotey.sh
```

For correctness, here is `.timer` file:

```
# /etc/systemd/system/rsync_to_remotey.timer
# or : /home/$USER/.config/systemd/user/rsync_to_remotey.timer
[Unit]
Description=Runs every 30 minutes rsync USER X data to REMOTE Y

[Timer]
OnBootSec=30min
AccuracySec=1h
OnCalendar=*:0/30
Unit=rsync_to_remotey.service

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: See also rsync's `--max-delete=NUM` option. Also, systemd's `AssertPathIsDirectory` (differs from Condition… in whether its an error).

Answer (score 11):

I was also looking for an explanation and the man-pages on a recent Raspberry Pi Jessie image sort of gave me one.

I first looked here: `man 7 systemd`
which then lead me to look at:
    [`man 5 systemd.unit`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#)

which provided the following:

> `RequiresMountsFor=`
>
> Takes a space-separated list of absolute paths. Automatically adds dependencies of type `Requires=` and `After=` for all mount units required to access the specified path.
>
> Mount points marked with noauto are not mounted automatically and will be ignored for the purposes of this option. If such a mount should be a requirement for this unit, direct dependencies on the mount units may be added (`Requires=` and `After=` or some other combination).

A little farther down in the man page,

> `ConditionArchitecture=`, `ConditionVirtualization=`, `ConditionHost=`, `ConditionKernelCommandLine=`, `ConditionSecurity=`, `ConditionCapability=`, `ConditionACPower=`, `ConditionNeedsUpdate=`, `ConditionPathExists=`, `ConditionPathExistsGlob=`, `ConditionPathIsDirectory=`, `ConditionPathIsSymbolicLink=`, `ConditionPathIsMountPoint=`, `ConditionPathIsReadWrite=`, `ConditionDirectoryNotEmpty=`, `ConditionFileNotEmpty=`, `ConditionFileIsExecutable=`, `ConditionNull=`
>
> Before starting a unit verify that the specified condition is true. If it is not true, the starting of the unit will be skipped, however all ordering dependencies of it are still respected. A failing condition will not result in the unit being moved into a failure state. The condition is checked at the time the queued start job is to be executed.

For what it's worth, I'm going with `ConditionPathIsMountPoint=`:

> `ConditionPathIsMountPoint=` is similar to `ConditionPathExists=` but verifies whether a certain path exists and is a mount point.